# PLS-00302: component 'stored procedure' must be declared

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure, toad

tengo el siguiente sp que no puedo debugear porque me devuelve error PLS-00302: component 'SP_VALIDAR_FECINICIO' must be declared.

Alguna idea?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ownerreintegros.SP_VALIDAR_FECINICIO
 (
    PID_BENEFICIARIO         IN NUMBER,
    PID_PLANMEDICOBENEF      IN NUMBER,
    PRESULT                       IN  OUT NUMBER
 )

 AS
 
   VFECHA_INICIO VARCHAR2(200);
  
    BEGIN
      
      SELECT FECHA_INICIO INTO VFECHA_INICIO 
        FROM VW_RELPLANMEDICOBENEF 
        WHERE  ID_PLAN_MEDICO = 123456798
        AND ID_BENEFICIARIO = PID_BENEFICIARIO 
        AND ID_PLANMEDICOBENEF = PID_PLANMEDICOBENEF 
        AND ROWNUM = 1;
       

        
         SELECT COUNT (*) INTO PRESULT
         FROM  VW_RELPLANMEDICOBENEF VW
         WHERE  VW.id_plan_medico = 123456789
         AND VW.ID_BENEFICIARIO = PID_BENEFICIARIO
         AND VW.id_planmedicobenef != PID_PLANMEDICOBENEF 
         AND TO_DATE(VW.FECHA_INICIO,'dd/MM/yyyy') > TO_DATE(VFECHA_INICIO,'dd/MM/yyyy');
         
         EXCEPTION WHEN
         NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            raise_application_error (-20000, SQLERRM);
         END;
     

 /
```

le asigno valores en el execute >pl/sql debugger y me tira error
ORA-06550: line 11, column 14:
PLS-00302: component 'SP_VALIDAR_FECINICIO' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: lo estás llamando teniendo en cuenta el package `ownerreintegros`? Lo estás llamando con un usuario con permisos suficientes para invocarlo? El package `ownerreintegros` y el package body están compilados sin errores?

Comment: hola @Alfabravo como estas? no lo estoy llamando, lo estoy debugeando desde el mismo editor donde cree el sp y le estoy pasando dos datos reales de la tabla

Comment: Lo más de bien! Lo malo es que los comentarios no son ni deben ser un chat; para eso está el [chat] :D Estoy atento a que añadas las aclaraciones. Y por eso mismo: si creaste el SP dentro de un package, la definición debe regenerarse para que oracle sepa que hay un nuevo procedimiento allá adentro. Revisa y recompila